# When should I close a statement in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Should a statement be reused as many time as possible or there's a limitation?

If there is a limitation, when is the right time to close it?

Is creating and closing statement a costly operation?

Comment: please clarify what you mean, with example code

Comment: What does closing a statement mean?

Comment: Are you talking dynamic sql where you prepare and deallocate statements?

Answer (score -1):

Creating and closing a statement doesn't really make sense. I believe what you mean is creating and closing a cursor. A cursor is a query that you iterate over the results of. Typically you see them in Stored Procedures and Functions in MySQL. Yes, they have a cost to open and close and you should iterate over the entire set.

Alternately you're talking about prepared statements such as you might create using the PDO library in PHP. In which case, you can use them as many times as possible and indeed you should, as this is more efficient.

Every time MySQL receives a statement, it translates that into its own internal logic and creates a query plan. Using prepared statements means it only has to do this once rather than every time you call it.

Finally, you might be trying to ask about a connection, rather than a statement. In which case, again, the answer is yes - you can (and should) use it as many time as you need as there's a significant performance impact of opening it. Though you don't want to keep it open longer than you need it because MySQL has a maximum number of connections it can open.

Hopefully one of those will answer your question.

Comment: Why has someone downvoted me? It's a vague question and I did my best to cover the possible meanings.